# Get most recent record from same column

Tags: dax, circular-dependency

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

| Ticker | Date | Transaction | Shares | Price | Average Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABEV3 | 01/Mar/2021 | Purchase | 77 | $12.93 | $12.93 |
| ABEV3 | 04/May/2021 | Purchase | 73 | $13.60 | $13.26 |
| ABEV3 | 04/Jun/2021 | **Sale** | 150 | $17.91 | **$13.26** |
| ABEV3 | 28/Jun/2021 | Purchase | 62 | $16.01 | $16.01 |
| ABEV3 | 29/Oct/2021 | **Sale** | 62 | $15.62 | **$16.01** |
| ALSO3 | 07/Jan/2021 | Purchase | 39 | $25.12 | $25.12 |
| ALSO3 | 03/Feb/2021 | **Sale** | 39 | $27.20 | **$25.12** |
| ALSO3 | 29/Jun/2021 | Purchase | 36 | $27.53 | $27.53 |
| ALSO3 | 07/Jan/2022 | Purchase | 56 | $17.85 | $21.64 |
| ALSO3 | 30/Mar/2022 | **Sale** | 92 | $22.61 | **$21.64** |

Whenever there is a row with a PURCHASE the measure under the "Average Cost" column will recalculate a new average cost for that particular ticker.

And whenever there is a row with a **SALE** all the measure needs to do is to pick up the latest calculated average cost for that same ticker from *that same column*.

Every way I tried to do that I incur **circular dependency error** on my DAX code.

How can I do that while avoiding circular dependency?

Comment: How are you calculating the average cost and what is you expected output ?

Comment: Pretty much a similar way you proposed on your answer, by dividing accumulated purchase amount by accumulated purchased shares

Comment: I need the expected output for the input you provided

Comment: This 'Average cost' measure will enable the creation of a 'Total cost of shares sold' measure that in turn will enable the creation of other profitability measures, such as 'Total gain/(loss)', 'Gain/(loss) per share', '% gain/(loss) over revenue' and so on. Basically further measures that will help me build a P&L and then other visuals that go along with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that you are trying to perform a calculation where the result depends on previously computed results within the same column, which creates a circular dependency in DAX.
You can create a new calculated column to calculate the cumulative purchase amount and the cumulative shares bought up to each row. Then, you can use these values to calculate the average cost.

I created a column for `Cumulative Purchase Amount` to sum the purchase amount (Shares * Price) for each ticker up to the current row.

Then I created another column for `Cumulative Shares Bought` to sum the shares for each ticker up to the current row, taking into account both purchases and sales (subtract shares for sales).

Then I divided the cumulative purchase amount by the cumulative shares bought to calculate the average cost.

```
Cumulative Purchase Amount = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        Table,
        Table[Ticker] = EARLIER(Table[Ticker]) &&
        Table[Date] <= EARLIER(Table[Date]) &&
        Table[Transaction] = "Purchase"
    ),
    Table[Shares] * Table[Price]
)

Cumulative Shares Bought = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        Table,
        Table[Ticker] = EARLIER(Table[Ticker]) &&
        Table[Date] <= EARLIER(Table[Date])
    ),
    IF(Table[Transaction] = "Purchase", Table[Shares], -Table[Shares])
)

Average Cost = 
IF(
    Table[Transaction] = "Purchase",
    Table[Cumulative Purchase Amount] / Table[Cumulative Shares Bought],
    LOOKUPVALUE(Table[Average Cost], Table[Date], MAXX(FILTER(Table, Table[Ticker] = EARLIER(Table[Ticker]) && Table[Date] < EARLIER(Table[Date])), Table[Date]))
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, my calculation setup uses that same rationale you're using of accumulating purchase amount and shares bought and divide them up. However, since in Excel there's a way to pick up a value from a prior row within the same column without resorting to the use of helper columns (by increasingly growing the lookup range up to the prior row using OFFSET or INDEX), so it would really baffle me if there's no way to do the same in DAX. WIth that said, I still think there might be a coding approach that would allow to do so in DAX, I just don't know how.

Comment: If you keep thinking in Excel and implement in DAX you will struggle a lot. Start thinking in DAX and implement in DAX

Comment: Hey @Amira, I implemented your proposed code to the dot and it also throws a circular dependency error. Please look at the last piece "Average Cost": the LOOKUPVALUE function's first argument calls for "Average Cost" itself, so the error comes up. That "Average Cost" piece had to be a calculated column since measures do not accept IF statements at its very start.